# Find index of the key in a dictionary of list

Tags: python

Given a dictionary of lists

```
node_to_index = {"global": [0],
                  "l_eye": list(range(42, 48)),
                  "r_eye": list(range(36, 42)),
                  "l_brow": list(range(22, 27)),
                  "r_brow": list(range(17, 22)),
                  "mouth": list(range(48, 68)),
                  "nose": list(range(27, 35)),
                 }
```

Given a number e.g. 37, it would return index of the "r_eye" key which is 2

Comment: The order of the keys in the dictionary is not guaranteed/defined unless you use an `OrderedDict`. `"r_eye"` having index `2` is meaningless and is not true.

Comment: Dictionaries are not indexed in the same way as lists; although Python 3 now stores dictionaries in order, you should not rely on this behaviour.

Comment: Maybe you should use ``ordereddict``

Comment: @MariusKuzm Why do you need the index instead of the key in the first place?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 5):

I'd go with a generator expression and `enumerate`, with `next` to shortcut as soon as the condition is satisfied:

```
next((ix for ix, (_,v) in enumerate(node_to_index.items()) if 37 in v), None)
# 2
```

Note that for python versions under 3.7, dictionaries' insertion order is not preserved. So you should consider using `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

node_to_index = OrderedDict({
    "global": [0],
    "l_eye": list(range(42, 48)),
    "r_eye": list(range(36, 42)),
    "l_brow": list(range(22, 27)),
    "r_brow": list(range(17, 22)),
    "mouth": list(range(48, 68)),
    "nose": list(range(27, 35)),
})

next((ix for ix, (_,v) in enumerate(node_to_index.items()) if 37 in v), None)
# 2
```

Comment: The downvote is because the question is not well-defined and the order of the keys in a dictionary should not be relied-upon unless it's an OrderedDict

Comment: No, that is not why I downvoted you. I downvoted because no answer to this question will ever be correct because the question is asking for something that is not well-defined and incorrect.

Comment: @Austin, That's an implementation detail of CPython 3.6 and only became standard in 3.7.

Comment: Reflected the fact in the answer @omer Added an orderedict alternative

Comment: But if `node_to_index` is already unorderd(3.5- Cpython or 3.6- python), `OrderedDict`'s order is unpredictable, too. You should sequence structure for creating `OrderedDict`.

Comment: I think I see what you mean @BoseongChoi you make a good point. updated the answer

Comment: If that is what you meant @BoseongChoi , I've updated the anwer. You might want to consider removing your downvote, since the answer is now correct?

Comment: I meant sequence like `list` or `tuple`. You can refer my answer. I'll remove downvote by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `collections.OrderedDict` to guarantee its order(index).

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

node_to_index = OrderedDict({
    "global": [0],
    "l_eye": list(range(42, 48)),
    "r_eye": list(range(36, 42)),
    "l_brow": list(range(22, 27)),
    "r_brow": list(range(17, 22)),
    "mouth": list(range(48, 68)),
    "nose": list(range(27, 35)),
})


def find_index(target: int) -> int:
    for idx, value in enumerate(node_to_index.values()):
        if target in value:
            return idx
    return -1


print(find_index(37))
```

output:

```
2
```

---

#### Note

If you are using CPython earlier than 3.6 or other interpreter earlier than 3.7, order of `dict` isn't guaranteed at even creation. So do this:

```py
node_to_index = OrderedDict([
    ('global', [0]),
    ('l_eye', list(range(42, 48))),
    ('r_eye', list(range(36, 42))),
    ('l_brow', list(range(22, 27))),
    ('r_brow', list(range(17, 22))),
    ('mouth', list(range(48, 68))),
    ('nose', list(range(27, 35))),
])
```

---

#### Policy for Absence

It is not quite relative OP's question, but appended for comments.
You have three options for absence of target value.

```py
return -1
```

```py
raise ValueError(f'{target} is not found')
```

```py
return None
```

Note that if the function returns in some cases, omitting otherwise's `return None` is not recommended by PEP8.

Comment: I think returning `None` or raising an exception would be better than just getting `-1` back.

Comment: @Guimoute I agree it could be. But I think it depends on policy. `list.index` raises an exception when target doesn't exist, whereas `str.find` returns `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

You just iterate through the items until 37 is in the list associated to that key.

Note that you have to handle edge cases like what to do if several lists contain the number (currently it's the first one that is returned) or if no list contains it (currently it returns `None`).

```
def find_number(number, my_dict):
    for n, (key, value) in enumerate(my_dict.items()):
        if number in value:
            return n

node_to_index = {"global": [0],
                 "l_eye": list(range(42, 48)),
                 "r_eye": list(range(36, 42)),
                 "l_brow": list(range(22, 27)),
                 "r_brow": list(range(17, 22)),
                 "mouth": list(range(48, 68)),
                 "nose": list(range(27, 35)),
                }

find_number(37, node_to_index) # returns 2
```

Comment: thanks, this returns the actual key but not the index of the key. I have found a solution myself but as others have mentioned that doing this might be unreliable

Comment: @dspencer Aren't dictionaries always ordered now? Regardless, OP asked for a solution to get the index so my solution works. Their work should not rely on the order/index, not mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
node_to_index = {"global": [0],
                 "l_eye": list(range(42, 48)),
                 "r_eye": list(range(36, 42)),
                 "l_brow": list(range(22, 27)),
                 "r_brow": list(range(17, 22)),
                 "mouth": list(range(48, 68)),
                 "nose": list(range(27, 35)),
                 }


def get_key(val):
    pos = 0
    for key, value in node_to_index.items():
         for elem in value:
             if elem == val:
                 return pos
         pos += 1


print(get_key(27))
```

Comment: @dspencer not since Python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that the value is present in one of the lists, you could use the index() method on a list comprehension:

```
value = 37
index = [value in nodes for nodes in node_to_index.values()].index(True)

print(index) # 2
```

Note that using a dictionary for this is probably not the best choice.  You seem to only need a list of tuples.  This would make the index more reliable and meaningful:

```
node_to_index = [ ( "global", [0]),
                  ( "l_eye",  list(range(42, 48) ),
                  ( "r_eye",  list(range(36, 42) ),
                  ( "l_brow", list(range(22, 27) ),
                  ( "r_brow", list(range(17, 22) ),
                  ( "mouth",  list(range(48, 68) ),
                  ( "nose",   list(range(27, 35) )
                ]

value = 37
index = [value in nodes for _,nodes in node_to_index].index(True)
```